# Access Private Docker Registry with a DoD CAC

Tags: docker, ssl, smartcard

We have a privately hosted docker repo that we wish to protect with "2-factor" authentication via DoD CAC (PKI, PIV, X.509, Smart Card).

Setting up an HTTPS reverse proxy in front of the docker repo (in our case NexusOSS-based) that requires DoD CACs is simple,
but I don't see an obvious way to have the `docker pull` command interact with a the CAC reader hardware.